# Handling FaultExceptions in SharePoint WebService

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, sharepoint, exception

I'm looking for a way to handle Server-Exception on a WebService in association with SharePoint and pass the correct Exception to the Client. Currently the Client gets the Internal Error (500) Exception. I want to pass more information about the Exception instead of the 500 to the client.

My Current Status: 
With c#, I defined a WebService and associated functions where the Exception  appears.

I searched online and implemented following Points:
I Catch that general Exception and throw a FaultException.

Code Example with forced Exception:

```
public object ServiceAction()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("This is a Test-Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log(ex.Message);
        throw new FaultException<Exception>(ex, "This Exception is my Test");
    }
}
```

On the web.config i also add the Behavior "includeExceptionDetailInFaults" and set it true:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The Client calls the WebService with a JavaScript-Fetch:

```
fetch('https://customer.sharepoint.local/_vti_bin/customer.SharePoint/customer.service.asmx/ServiceAction',
{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },

})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    if (!data.d) {
        console.log(data)
    }

})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

The Problem now is that the client still gets the Internal Error (500) Exception.

Thanks for helping in advance.